# Display MySql database errors in php

Tags: php, mysqli

How can MySql database errors like 'trying to insert duplicate record' be captured and displayed in PHP?

get this error when inserting -- Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean.

In this case i know I'm getting it because I'm trying to insert a duplicate record. does php/mysql not give specific errors? which i could display on screen for end user to understand .

```
function querydb($sql){

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              echo "Failed to connect to  Database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              return 0;
            }

            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error in the query.." . mysqli_error($result));
            $con->close();

            return $result;
}
```

Comment: Provide more information on how you access the DB. Are you using PDO, MySQLi ?

Comment: This?:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Googeling your thread title leads me [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). If this does not help you, be more specific,

Comment: @Saifur                                                                                                                                   $sql = "delete from student where Sid='$Sid';";

 function querydb($sql){

   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to  Database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      return 0;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error in the query.." . mysqli_error($result));
    $con->close();

    return $result;
 }

Comment: Echo your $sql, maybe $Sid is returning null.

Comment: @Dimas Pante    done that. Its not null.

Comment: You're simply looking for `mysqli_error($con)` and `if ($result)`. Also scrape your whole `querydb` function; as it obviously deters from utilizing parameter binding. Preferrably read up on PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

First turn on the error reporting. Add on top of your file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then if the log doesn't make sense to you, try writing the SQL and pasting it into phpMyAdmin, it'll probably show a different error (if it's being caused by sql).